# Does Boto3 encrypt the payload during transmission when invoking a lambda function?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, encryption, aws-lambda, boto3

I am using the Python AWS API. I would like to invoke a lambda function from client code, but I have not been able to find documentation on whether the payload sent during invocation is encrypted.

Can someone watching the network potentially snoop on the AWS invocation payload? Or is the payload transmitted over a secure channel?

Comment: All communication with the Lambda service is over HTTPS whether it is via boto3, AWSCLI, some other SDK or the AWS console.  Lambda does not support any other protocol.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. Before you invoke a lambda (or do anything), you'll create a client object, which accepts various parameters including `use_ssl` - for example - that is `true` by default. The ensures the traffic between your client and AWS is protected in transit. Now, the payload itself is whatever you send. If you send plaintext, the lambda gets plaintext. If you send ciphertext, the lambda will receive ciphertext. It's not encrypting and decrypting your payload in the invoke lambda call.

References...

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/core/session.html
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

If you turn on the debug logging you should see how exactly is data transmitted. Or try `netstat` or Wireshark to see if it makes connection to port 443 rather than 80.

From my experience with `boto3` and S3 (not Lambda) it uses HTTPS, which I would consider somewhat secure. I hope the certificates are verified...